# Why does overwriting `__str__` of an object at runtime not work?

Tags: python, magic-methods

Given the following interactive Python interpreter session:

```
>>> class c(object): pass 
>>> o=c()
>>> str(o)
'<__main__.c object at 0x7f865da68820>'
>>> o.__str__ = lambda _: 'test'
>>> str(o)
'<__main__.c object at 0x7f865da68820>'
```

I would expect the second invocation of `str` on `o` to say `'test'`.

What is wrong with my assumption here and how do I overwrite the string representation of an object at runtime then?

Comment: Because it's looked up on the class, not the instance.

Comment: But once the instance has a member named `__str__` it should take precedence over the class one, as is the case with regular and a lot of other magic methods. How else would I be able to over-ride it for just one instance? "You don't!" is not a sensible answer in my opinion, given Python's dynamic nature. Besides it would be inconsistent.

Comment: Please read the answer to the dupe and the Python docs it links to, which explain this.